# How can I trigger the Twitter intents events programmatically?

Tags: javascript, events, testing, twitter, qunit

The Facebook JS SDK has the equivalent of jQuery's `trigger()` function, `FB.Event.fire`
that allows you to trigger the handlers you attach for particular events. Its helpful for my unit tests in QUnit. It works basically as you'd expect it to; `FB.Event.fire("comment.create", location.href);` fires my handlers for the `comment.create` event.

[Twitter's object](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents/events) for Web Intents, `twttr` appears to have something that looks like it could be similar, `twttr.events.trigger()`, but its undocumented.

Except, I can't figure out how to trigger it correctly in code, without it throwing an error.

How can I programmatically test the handlers that I attach to this object?

For code like:

```
twttr.events.bind("click", function(intent){
    console.dir(intent);
});
```

I'd expect to be able to trigger it by doing something like: `twttr.events.trigger("click")`

Everything I try results in an error, and I'm not able to decipher the [obfuscated source code](http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js).

I've put up some basic code on the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YL6SN/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello Yahel nice question,

It should work if you call this:

```
twttr.events.trigger("click", {});
```

It expects a second parameter that is the object that is passed back to your callback. When it happens naturally this object is populated with other parameters

```
{target: b,region: "intent",type: "click",data: {}}
```

If you pass an empty object like I proposed it will work as well but in your callback you receive the object only with the `type` property since this is added by the trigger.

And that was exactly the error you triggered when you don't pass a second parameter. It tries to add the `type` parameter to `undefined` and and then dies.

Comment: Nice. Thanks, Eduardo. http://jsfiddle.net/YL6SN/2/ works. It seems like the `target` is supposed to be the DOM element of the Twitter iframe (which is crucial for my testing).